# Sql Server 2008 CDC Problems

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, cdc, change-data-capture

I am new to CDC and want to know if there is any problem in using CDC. I am targeting to use it for audit purpose i.e. Log activity using CDC and then show the same to user when needed. Does it record the exact changes to all fields in table in all cases

Comment: This question should probably be moved to server fault.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will capture only the columns you specify, of only the tables you specify, and yes, it will have a before value and an after value in the capture tables. The capture tables do not store the data indefinitely, they are purged after 3 days by default, so you'll need a process, like SSIS, to harvest the data and store it permanently for reporting.

Comment: The time that the data is persisted is configurable. 3 days is by default but you can always increase it.